# Getting an error when deploying a Django app to Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django app but I am getting a push rejected error(Traceback attached). I am using whitenoise to handle the static files and done the correct configuration in settings.py file. This error has really been bugging me .

```
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 17, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
           django.setup()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
           app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
           mod = import_module(mod_path)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whitenoise'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Are you sure that the whitenoise module is in your requirements.txt file?

Comment: The key part of the error message is `No module named 'whitenoise'`. It looks like you need to add `whitenoise` to your requirements file.

Comment: whitenoise module is included in my requirements.txt and I am still getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not disabling statics on the app I was to deploy
I ran the following command
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 -app 'appname'

Answer (score 0):

In your development environment, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` This will add all of your currently installed modules and, assuming your development environment has all of its dependencies, will enable Heroku to install all needed modules.

Comment: I have the requirements.txt file already and I am getting the same error. I was thinking I should change another module to handle the static files instead of whitenoise

Comment: Does your requirements.txt have whitenoise in it?

Comment: yes whitenoise is included in the file.Below is my requirements.txt file   
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.0.1
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
django-fontawesome==1.0
django-mailjet==0.3.1
django-sendgrid==1.0.1
django-smtp-ssl==1.0
idna==2.8
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.2
requests==2.22.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.7
whitenoise==5.0.1